# MissingManifestResourceException in .net core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to read a localization value from Resource File in .net core class library but I got an exception. I add my class library in a .net core wep api project.
These are my resource file "Resource.de.resx", "Resource.en.resx", "Resource.tr.resx", they are in root folder of my class library project. There is no resource file in web api project. When I build my class library three folder are created (de,en,tr), in these folder there is a dll called 'XXX.Model.Core.resources.dll'.

> An exception of type 'System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.
>   Make sure "Resource.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "class library" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.

here is my class library project.json file :

```
{  
"version": "1.0.0-*",
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DynamicLinq": "1.0.3.3",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1",
    "System.ComponentModel.Annotations": "4.3.0",
    "System.ComponentModel.Primitives": "4.3.0",
    "System.Reflection.Extensions": "4.3.0",
    "System.Resources.Reader": "4.3.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  },
 **"buildOptions": {
    "embed":
 { "include": [ "Resource.de.resx", "Resource.en.resx", "Resource.tr.resx" ]}}}**
```

here is my class which is try to access resources :

```
 var resourceManager = new ResourceManager("Resource", typeof(LanguageSupportedException).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

resourceManager.GetString("xx");
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: I think you should be able to just read the resources directly like `<yourlibrary.namespace.Resources.xx`. Also you should have a default resx called `Resources.resx`

Answer (score 0):

I also encounterd this message in XAML, in combination with WPFLocalizationExtension.
I had this piece of XAML code:

```
<Label 
    Content="{lex:Loc WindspeedArea}" 
    ToolTip="{lex:Loc TipResources:TT_WindSpeed}"/>
```

WindspeedArea is in Resources.resx.

TT_WindSpeed is in TipResources.resx.

Then I got the idea to combine all strings in Resources.resx.

And forgot to remove all the "TipResource:" prefixes from all XAML files.

Thus getting the Exception. Many times.